# How to use (_ map op) from Z3-LIB in z3py

Tags: arrays, z3py

Z3-LIB supports the operators for the extended Array theory such as (_ map op). But, how can we use this operator in Z3py?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
b = Map(f, a1, a2)
```

with a1, a2 and b array variables. The first parameter f has to be a function declaration, so using, e.g., z3.And does not work for me. Instead, I introduced a custom function f and another axiom to make it equivalent to And. But maybe you don't need the predefined ones.